# Different limit_req for $request_uri part

Tags: nginx, rewrite, rate-limiting

I want configure different rate limiting for php-fpm.

I want to:

1. static files had no limits,
2. PHP requests had limits,
3. PHP requests to `/ admin /.+` had different limits.

I have problem with implementation point 3. Now I test:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=php:10m rate=2r/s;
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=admin:10m rate=9r/s;

server {
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    limit_req_status 429;
# limitng works, server return 404
    location ~ /admin/ {limit_req zone=admin...}

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        limit_req zone=php burst=9 delay=4;
#limit_req not allowed here
        if($request_uri ~ /admin) {limit_req zone=admin...}
#not update limits (lower)
        location ~ ^/admin/ {limit_req zone=admin...}
#negative matching returns index.php content
        location location ~ ^/(?!(admin)) {limit_req zone=php...}
    }
}
```

Also is `limit_req_zone $request_uri` but  if I understand, this create different pools for `/admin/1` and `/admin/2`.

//update 1:

I need different pools for request like:
`/index.php?/.*` and less strict for `/index.php?/admin/.*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the `limit_req_zone` directive [documentation](https://nginx.org/r/limit_req_zone):

> Requests with an empty key value are not accounted.

So just use two `limit_req` directives in your PHP handler location and made one of the zone keys empty depending on the `$request_uri` (either first or second request limit rate won't be applied in this case):

```
map $request_uri $is_admin {
    ~^/admin/  1;
    default    0;
}
map $is_admin $php_key {
    0 $binary_remote_addr;
    # an empty value otherwise by default
}
map $is_admin $admin_key {
    1 $binary_remote_addr;
    # an empty value otherwise by default
}

limit_req_zone $php_key zone=php:10m rate=2r/s;
limit_req_zone $admin_key zone=admin:10m rate=9r/s;

server {
    ...
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        limit_req zone=php ...
        limit_req zone=admin ...
        ...
```

Comment: pure magic! works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

According to [documetation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html)  limit_req is allowed only in 
http, server, location.

I would suggest to exclude 1 & 2 and have common location with same policy as for / and admin :

```
server {
listen 127.0.0.1:8088;
location / {
content_by_lua_block {
    ngx.say("root")
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_OK)

}
}
location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|bmp|swf|js|html|txt)$ {
content_by_lua_block {
    ngx.say("static")
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_OK)

}
}
location ~* "^\/admin($|\/(.*)$)" {
content_by_lua_block {
    ngx.say("processed by php with first ratelimit")
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_OK)

}
}
location ~* "\.php$" {
content_by_lua_block {
    ngx.say("processed by php with second ratelimit")
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_OK)

}
}
}
```

And tests:

```
# curl 127.0.0.1:8088/admin
processed by php with first ratelimit
# curl 127.0.0.1:8088/admin.php
processed by php with second ratelimit
# curl 127.0.0.1:8088/admin/
processed by php with first ratelimit
# curl 127.0.0.1:8088/admin/test.php
processed by php with first ratelimit
# curl 127.0.0.1:8088/test/php
root
```

Comment: We didn't understand each other. Route `/admin/` must be processed by php, but should have a different rate-limiting.

Comment: I updated my unswer with test codeblock

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the solution into to your answer. I have the situation: `/index.php?/some` - rate-limiting-1 and  `/index.php?/admin` - less-strict-rate-limiting

Comment: I didn;t get properly from first time) Updated once more

Comment: Yup for `location ~* "^\/admin($|\/(.*)$)" ` limiting work OK, but php not. I can't imagine repeating the entire `php` section. I also considered using `include`, but I don't really like to split the domain configuration into 2 files.

Comment: yes in such case you will need to duplicate your php configuration inside 2 locations or create a separate file and include it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98367/discussion-between-user2986553-and-bato3).